# Load different css depending on their URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i load different css depending on their url

**example:**

```
https://domain1.tld & https://*.domain.tld => css1.css
https://domain2.tld & https://*.domain2.tld => css2.css
https://elsedomain.tld & https://*.elsedomain.tld => css3.css
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not a good idea to load CSS with JS, unless it's for elements that don't show until JS shows them. You are better off inluding the correct CSS file in the HTML by doing it server-side. There is not enough information given as to why this wouldn't be possible.

Comment: You could use an apache RewriteRule maybe? I'm not good with that so you need to look it up yourself, just a suggestion. Or is that not a solution for you?

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use JavaScript (rather than being able to build it into a .NET project or example) you can use a case statement looking at the host:

```
function mymodule_preprocess_html() {
  var site = window.location.hostname;

  switch (site) {
    case 'siteurl1':
      //Add code for site 1 here
      break;
    case 'siteurl2':
      //Add code for site 2 here
      break;
    case 'siteurl3':
      //Add code for site 3 here
      break;

  }
}
```

The code for using JavaScript to insert a CSS file can then be added and specified as below:

```
function mymodule_preprocess_html() {
  var site = window.location.hostname;

  switch (site) {
    case 'siteurl1':
         var head  = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
         var link  = document.createElement('link');
         link.id   = cssId;
         link.rel  = 'stylesheet';
         link.type = 'text/css';
         link.href = 'http://website.com/css/stylesheet1.css';
         link.media = 'all';
         head.appendChild(link);
      break;
    case 'siteurl2':
         var head  = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
         var link  = document.createElement('link');
         link.id   = cssId;
         link.rel  = 'stylesheet';
         link.type = 'text/css';
         link.href = 'http://website.com/css/stylesheet2.css';
         link.media = 'all';
         head.appendChild(link);
      break;
    case 'siteurl3':
         var head  = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
         var link  = document.createElement('link');
         link.id   = cssId;
         link.rel  = 'stylesheet';
         link.type = 'text/css';
         link.href = 'http://website.com/css/stylesheet3.css';
         link.media = 'all';
         head.appendChild(link);
      break;

  }
}
```

There are probably tidier ways of doing it...

Comment: Thank you for that, can i use wildcards in domain names? or it is suffisant to define domain.tld?

Comment: You do know `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];` is PHP right? You can't just put that in JavaScript.

Comment: You're right sorry - should be `window.location.hostname` I've updated the answer.

Comment: @putvande if he/she can use `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` in PHP then they can just output the link to the correct CSS file.

Comment: I think maybe its better to do that into php :)

Comment: If it's possible for you to do that it would be more reliable (in case JavaScript is disabled for example)

Comment: `if $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == "domain.tld" {
// css1
}`

So?

Answer (score -1):

Since all these are in different domains, you could just have the css file linked in the markup that gets served.

Comment: the css files are all on the same vhost/domain i only want to take different css if the domain/url changes.

Comment: Instead of having all the css for all the domains, just have the css that's needed.

Comment: What sense this make? when i need different css (background-images, buttons and so on) :S

Comment: What i meant is keep ONLY what's needed for a domain.

Comment: and i think you don't really know what you are speaking... the different domains are all on the same webspace/server and i need that the css load dynamicly when the domainname changes...